# What is the Ubuntu Loco Day?

Tags: community, locoteams

What is the purpose of this day?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LoCoDays:

> LoCo Days were designed to encourage LoCo Teams to start doing more Classroom sessions in their native languages.

LoCo Days are the LoCo equivalent of User Days:

> User Days was created to be a set of courses offered during a one day period to teach the beginning or intermediate Ubuntu user the basics to get them started with Ubuntu.